# javascript - function as argument

Tags: javascript

I was just wondering;

Why does this work;

```
    test = function(message) {
        console.log('xxx');
    }

    setTimeout(test, 3000);
```

but not this;

```
    test = function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }

    setTimeout(test('xxx'), 3000);
```

I know it should be written like this;
But the version above would be so much more convenient...

```
    test = function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }

    setTimeout(function() { test('xxx'); }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the returned result of `test` to the callback argument of `setTimeout` instead of passing the function reference.

```
function callback(callback) {
    callback();
}
function say(message) {
    console.log(message);
    // this function doesn't return anything
}
// callback(say('Hello World!')) === callback() because say(message) doesnt return anything.
```

Answer (score 0):

In your 2nd example it is immediately calling `test` with the string `xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function immediatly in your second example. To pass the string, you can `bind` the parameter instead of calling it on its own:

```
setTimeout(test.bind(null,'xxxx'), 3000);
```

```js
    test = function(message) {
        alert(message);
    }

    setTimeout(test.bind(null,'xxxx'), 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write a function name with parenthesis, it will call it instead giving reference.

Answer (score 0):

The second one doesn't work because setTimeout requires a function as a parameter (which it will call) and the second version you show has test('xxx') which means "the result of calling test('xxx')" which is undefined - *not* a function.